# My form "post" is not working

Tags: php, html

here is only part of my code, the action does not well ...action. when i view in the google javascript tools i have an id in the action line
when i hit the submit button, nothing happens, its suppose to go to php/form.php with ID 28 in this instance

```
 ......
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result))
 {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
   {  
?>
<form name="form-list" method="post" action='php/form.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>' >
 <table> 
   <tr>
     <td valign="top">
        <label for="surname">Surname</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top"> 
       <?php echo $row["title"]; ?> 
     </td>                           
   </tr>                                
   <tr>
     <td valign="top"> 
       <label for="name">Id</label> 
     </td>                   
     <td valign="top"> 
      <input type="text" value='<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>' name="name" maxlength="50" size="30"> 
     </td>        
   </tr>     
   <tr>
     <td valign="top">            
       <input type="button" value="Submit" />   
     </td>
   </tr>        
 <?php } } ?>   
</table>    
</form>  .....
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, because you put it there: action='php/form.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>' >
Just can't get what is your question. If you need to pass an id use hidden input.

Comment: huh? i dont understand?

Comment: What is the problem? It's working well. The $row["id"] is 28...

Comment: its not working on my side, that is what i cannot understand, what can the problem be?

Comment: Plz elaborate. You dont get the post element or what ?

Comment: Because your button type is not submit, change it to submit, it will fix.

Comment: What is not working ? Are you not getting thing (`$_POST['name_of_form']`) .

Comment: You are passing id in your action to form.php . If you want to send this id value to your form.php , then make your action='php/form.php' and in form.php use $id=$_POST['name']; where name have the value of your id as I can see in your code. And yes do change button type to submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The input type is not `button` it is `submit`.
The value attribute just changes the written text on the button but does not change it's behavior.

### Note to the other answers:

Using POST is fine if he handles the request in the right way. In the given code example everything except the submit button works and is fine.

In this case the id is transmitted as a GET and all other values are submitted via POST. **You can mix them**.

Later you do have to use `$_GET["id"]` and `$_POST["name"]`.. or you can even use `$_REQUEST["..."]` for all of them.